# Custom print service for WebApp without AGOL Enterprise account?

Tags: arcgis-server, printing, web-service

I understand that in order to print to a custom layout from an ArcGIS Web App, I would need to set up a print service on a server.

Although the whole process of getting a layout from ArcGIS Pro to a print service is clear as mud to me, would it be possible to set up a print service with some other server to use custom layouts for printing from a WebApp or would the print service HAVE to run off of an ArcGIS Enterprise server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're comparing when you say

> set up a print service with some other server to use custom layouts for printing from a WebApp Or would the print service HAVE to run off of an ArcGIS Enterprise
> server

The print service is a geoprocessing service. This powers 'web printing' in the ArcGIS world. The app calls the GP Service which facilitates the print. A GP Service can only be published to ArcGIS Enterprise (specifically the Server component).

If you want to add your own layouts to the print service, you need to follow the [share custom layouts](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/tutorial-publish-additional-layouts-for-printing-with-arcgis-pro.htm) help topic.